# About the equation $|HK|=\frac{|H|.|K|}{|H\cap K|}$

Tags: group-theory

For simplicity, consider $G$ a finite *abelian* group. Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Then we know that $|HK| = \frac{|H|.|K|}{|H\cap K|}$.

**Question:** Does this relation holds if we assume that $H,K$ are simply *(non-empty) subsets* of $G$, and we assume that $H, K$ are not disjoint?

Comment: First, you need to be careful, as then they might have empty intersection, and the quotient does not make sense. And try with some $2$-element subsets of some small group.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look at $G=S_3$, and take $H=\{(1), (12)\}$, $K=\{(1), (12), (132)\}$. Then $|HK|=4$.

Abelian hint: look at a cyclic group of order $4$: $G=\langle a \rangle$, where $a^4=1$. Take $H=\{1,a\}$, $K=\{1,a,a^3\}$. Then $|HK|=4$.

Comment: The OP wanted an abelian group though.

Comment: Ah oversaw that ... thanks. Will correct.

Comment: Yeah, it does not make any huge difference.

Comment: BTW, something that just occurred to me: Is it possible to find a non-empty subset $A$ which is not a subgroup but such that $|AB|$ has the "correct" size for all subgroups $B$?

Comment: @Tobias Nice question - this warrants a separate post!

Comment: Well, I wanted to think a bit more about a possible example before doing that (and you might have an example handy which would save me time).

Comment: OK, fair enough - btw you should infer that "for all subgroups $B$ having a non-empty intersection with $A$"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Take $H=\{0,1,4,8,12\}$, $K=\{0,1,40,41,42\}$ in $Z_{56}$.

Then $H+K=\{0,1,40,41,42,2,41,43,4,5,44,45,46,8,9,48,49,50,12,13,52,53,54\}$ with total number $23$ which is not less than or equal to $\frac{5\times 5}{2}=12.5$.